# Why javac produces different byte code for two seemingly very similar constructs?

Tags: java, bytecode, javap

Consider the very simple contrived example code :

```
 public class TestJavap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 3;
        int b = 7;
    }
}
```

javap produces this :

```
 public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0: iconst_3      
   1: istore_1      
   2: bipush        7
   4: istore_2      
   5: return
```

1. Why the compiler is producing different byte code for very similar fields `a` and `b`. Both are integral types initialized with constant literals.

   For `a` it fetches the constant from the pool via `iconst_3` and then stores it in the variable via `istore_1` whereas for b it uses a completely different mechanism (combination of `bipush` and  `istore`).

Comment: There is no `iconst_7`

Comment: Actually, neither instruction is fetching from the constant pool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
why the compiler is producing different byte code for very similar fields a and b
```

From integer `-1` **-** `5` `iconst_x`(x is number ranging from 0 - 5) is used that it is already a constant number bytecode.

```
iconst_m1   02      → -1    load the int value -1 onto the stack
iconst_0    03      → 0 load the int value 0 onto the stack
iconst_1    04      → 1 load the int value 1 onto the stack
iconst_2    05      → 2 load the int value 2 onto the stack
iconst_3    06      → 3 load the int value 3 onto the stack
iconst_4    07      → 4 load the int value 4 onto the stack
iconst_5    08      → 5 load the int value 5 onto the stack
```

Hence if the number is not a constant value of `iconst_` bytecode then it will be using the `bipush` bytecode.

More info on the [list of java bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) && [JVMS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/)

Comment: Also `iconst_m1` for -1.

Comment: You can reference the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/).

Comment: Of course, it will use `bipush` if the constant fits into the `byte` range only. Otherwise, if the value fits into the `short` range `sipush` will be used. If the value lies outside the `short` range, it has to be put to the constant pool and loaded via `ldc`. So now that we have talked about this we can go ahead and ask why `if(x==0)` is compiled differently than `if(x==1)`…